# Recover deleted files from Filevault 2

Tags: filevault, data-recovery

On one partition of an external drive encrypted with Filevault 2, I have accidentally deleted a folder and files. Does decryption also decrypt the deleted files?

Answer (score 1):

No - encryption/decryption is a completely separate process that will not affect what the OS sees as data (files/folders) versus available space.

You will need to run a file recovery program, such as [DiskDrill](http://www.cleverfiles.com/) or [Data Rescue](https://www.prosofteng.com/datarescue-mac-data-recovery/); the chance of success at retrieving your files will vary.

Finally, you should seriously consider a proper backup solution, anything from Apple's built-in [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250) to 3rd party solutions like [CrashPlan](https://www.crashplan.com/en-us/) or [BackBlaze](https://www.backblaze.com/).

Comment: Ok - Any pointers on a technical article that describes how Filevault 2 handles deletions of files? I've looked around extensively and come up short.

Comment: FileVault 2 doesn't have anything to do with deletions - that's handled by the OS instead.  FileVault encrypts the drive, waits for a successful challenge at boot to unlock that drive, then the OS runs as normal.  You should be focused on the specific version of OS X you're using and the format of the drive (likely jHFS+).